# Android - Eclipse Memory Analyze Tool - why reporting 9patch and bitmap from native android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, mat

Whatever android app i put into Eclipse memory analyzer tool i get two suspects that look like this:

[image]

These look like native android items.  Is there anything i can do to minimize the footprint ?

Comment: Create an empty project. Run that app. Take a heap dump. Run that dump through MAT. Anything that's in there is "baseline" and cannot really be removed. Anything not in there but in your real app's heap dump is incremental, based upon what you're using in Android. Generally speaking, what you are seeing are resources tied to widgets that you're using (e.g., button backgrounds for the nine-patches, the no-more-pages glow from `ViewPager`), and the only way to avoid those resources is to avoid those widgets.

Comment: Good point. Im looking for something like xcodes static code analyzer which is very user friendly, anything like this available ?

Comment: Since I have no idea what the "xcodes static code analyzer" is, I can't really answer that, sorry.